# Plumbing toilet fill tube runs into copper pipe picture attached

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, toilet, drainage

[image]

Any idea about whats going on here with the copper pipe?

Comment: Any idea where the copper tube goes?  Maybe to save a bucket when washing the floor.

Comment: It runs parallel to the main toilet drain all the way to the basement and out the main. Also where it t's off it doesnt flow down the overflow tube at all. Im scratching my head here none of my other toilets have this

Comment: It is a weird setup in any sense.

Comment: Would pull off the rubber tube from it and see what happens.  Stay close by.

Comment: Ya i pulled the fill tube off the pipe and placed it in the overfill tube and everything is fine. There has to be a purpose for someone to go to this length for installation, i just cant figure out what it would be lol

Comment: The only thing I could think(bad idea to do) of, is to keep an old unused P-trap filled with water, or someone had extra copper pipe around and wanted to weird you out.

Comment: Perhaps it was a source of water? Perhaps they had a way of pumping up water they capture from rain or something; perhaps some extreme water cost saving design? Or a way of dealing with a slow leak... it is so odd...

Comment: An amoeba ladder, similar to a salmon ladder, to allow the critters to migrate upstream, or it uses refill valve flutter to play *very* low bass notes through that length of copper tubing -- AKA "sewer flute". as created by PDQ Bach (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j5yy9xXMGk).

Comment: My question is what's the socket wrench for??

Comment: I do not see a supply line connected to the fill valve under the the tank... is there one? T think you should replace the fill valve with a new one, hook things up the way they should be, get rid of the copper tube and see what happens.

Comment: For your question - The inlet for the flush, which is supposed to be from the bottom, is damaged or not functioning. So the person has replaced the inlet to be served from an external factor using the copper pipe. If you open the flush from the bottom you will be able to confirm that. To me, it appears to be an amateur job. The person did not know how to solder a copper pipe and extend a proper inlet from a standard copper inlet pipe. So the person has provided an inlet from outside directly. Some more photos would be needed ideally. And are there three outlet pipes in the photo? or two? Its n

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your flush system was replaced.  The liner (looks like styrofoam) is interesting.  The intention there is either to reduce the amount of water per flush or to inhibit condensation on the outside of the tank due to cold water entering.  You can see it was roughly cut back to install the flapper.  I have absolutely seen in other toilets a small diameter tube going from the ball cock into the overflow pipe.  The tee fitting looks old and probably original.  Instructions for the replacement say the rubber hose should not terminate below the tank water level or water will continue to flow so I think the leg of the tee going downstairs is a jury-rig way of handling overflow.  A big waste of water.  The fix?  Replace the rubber hose ensuring it ends above the water line and eliminate the copper rigamarole.